# Custom font not displaying languages other than English properly on Windows

Tags: css, fonts, multilingual

My problem is a custom font works fine with the English language on Windows or Linux Chrome browser, but does not display other languages properly on Windows though it seems to work well on Linux.

I am using a custom font, "Source Sans Pro".

```
 body {
   font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
 }
```

Here are examples of rendering.

Linux rendering English

[image]

Linux rendering other languages ex:Tamil

[image]

Windows rendering English

[image]

Windows rendering other languages ex:Tamil

[image]

Let me know why it is happening and how to solve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Specifically, what other languages and how is it not rendering properly? A couple quick screenshots of the good and bad examples would help.

Comment: Are you sure, the language you are using supports characters of the desired langugae i.e. your language. Additionally 'have you added the fonts/styles of your choice language in your code???

Comment: i edited my post. please review it again.

Answer (score 0):

When debugging custom fonts, I open developer tools and do a few checks:

- Check network tab, **did the font file load?**
- Check elements, **is the fallback applied instead of my custom font?** In your example, using a fallback with serifs would make it much more obvious if the fallback was being applied.
- If the font is being loaded and applied, **is it capable of the styles I'm asking?** Refined bold or light styles, Cyrillic or other languages require additional files. For example, try selecting [Roboto](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto?selection.family=Roboto) and visit the Customize tab in the bottom drawer.

[image: Screenshot of Google Fonts Roboto font family and its customization options including languages]

There are multiple ways to load a custom font. Seeing as Source Sans Pro is available on Google Font, here's a link to their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started) for getting started.

Comment: i checked.font loaded correctly in all browser but it is too big and outside div or something not properly.